# DatabaseError: 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: 'Error in STUSCHOOLID' for column 'STU_SCHOOLID' at row 1

Tags: python, mysql

I am receiving data from a web form. I have eliminated the host, user, password and database info. Each time I get this error:

> DatabaseError: 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: 'Error in STUSCHOOLID' for column 'STU_SCHOOLID' at row 1.

If I put the `STUSCHOOLID = int(form.get("STUSCHOOLID", "Error in STUDENT SCHOOL ID")) as int` it says

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Error in BOOK ISBN’

Also, if I put it as `int(float(form.get....` it says

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: Error in BOOK ISBN.

```
 <%

 import mysql.connector
 cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host="", user="", password="", database="")
 cursor = cnx.cursor()

 STUSCHOOLID = form.get("STUSCHOOLID", "Error in STUDENT SCHOOL ID")
 STUFNAME = form.get("STUFNAME", "Error in STUDENT FIRST NAME")
 STULNAME = form.get("STULNAME", "Error in STUDENT LAST NAME")
 STUGENDER = form.get("STUGENDER", "Error in STUDENT GENDER")
 STUAGE = form.get("STUAGE", "Error in STUDENT AGE")
 STUYOS = form.get("STUYOS", "Error in STUDENT YEAR OF STUDY")
 BOOKISBN = form.get("BOOKISBN", "Error in BOOK ISBN")
 BOOKNAME = form.get("BOOKNAME", "Error in BOOK NAME")
 AUTHORID = form.get("AUTHORID", "Error in AUTHOR ID")
 BOOKPUBLISHER = form.get("BOOKPUBLISHER", "Error in BOOK PUBLISHER")
 DATEPUBLISHED = form.get("DATEPUBLISHED", "Error in DATE PUBLISHED")

 STUSCHOOLID = str(STUSCHOOLID)
 STUFNAME = str(STUFNAME)
 STULNAME = str(STULNAME)
 STUGENDER = str(STUGENDER)
 STUAGE = str(STUAGE)
 STUYOS = str(STUYOS) 
 BOOKISBN = str(BOOKISBN)
 BOOKNAME = str(BOOKNAME)
 AUTHORID = str(AUTHORID)
 BOOKPUBLISHER = str(BOOKPUBLISHER)
 DATEPUBLISHED = str(DATEPUBLISHED)

 insert1= "INSERT INTO STUDENT  values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);"
 values1 = (STUSCHOOLID, STUFNAME, STULNAME, STUGENDER, STUAGE, STUYOS)
 cursor.execute(insert1, values1)

 insert2 = "INSERT INTO BOOK values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s);"
 values2 = (BOOKISBN, BOOKNAME, AUTHORID, BOOKPUBLISHER, DATEPUBLISHED)
 cursor.execute(insert2, values2)

 cnx.commit()
 cursor.close()
 cnx.close()

 req.write("Records have been added to tables STUDENT & BOOK")

 %>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example is a great guide on how frame a question for the stack overflow team.  We would love to see the input data!